# How Do i Write a if statement on a jquery script?

Tags: jquery

Im trying to bind keys to a jQuery calculator - and trying to create an if statement. Tried a few ways with no luck, whats the correct way to do this?

Working script for one key:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 49) {
        $(".key.action").click();
    }
});
```

I want something like this to bind several keys:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which == 49) {
        $(".key.1").click();
        return;
    } else if e.which == 50) {
        $(".key.2").click();
        return;    
    }
});
```

Comment: What you have should work (assuming the missing bracket in the second `if` is a typo) - although the `return` statements are redundant given your logic flow. Is there a specific problem you have?

Comment: you missed a ' open parenthesis ' on this line after if ... else if e.which == 50) {

Comment: Not sure if i need the return statements - I basically tried to copy another script im using with if statements. I did get it working from the comments here - but now a keypress return two numbers instead of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed an open parenthesis on the second `if` statement:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 49){
        $(".key.1").click();
        return;
    } else if(e.which == 50){
        $(".key.2").click();
        return;    
    }
});
```

**EDIT**

Including a `$.stop` function to avoid multiple registers of the `keypress`:

```
$(document).keypress(function(e){
    if (e.which == 49){
        $(".key.1").click();
        $(e).stop();
        return;
    } else if(e.which == 50){
        $(".key.2").click();
        $(e).stop();
        return;    
    }
});
```

...although, testing both ways, I only see the `keypress` fire once.

[See Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/g59L8s46/) (pressing "1" includes `$.stop()`, pressing "2" doesn't)

Comment: Good spot. This could just be a typo in the question though.

Comment: Mate you're *everywhere*! I considered that, but I can't see another reason why the code wouldn't work...

Comment: that was it. I was pretty close then :) Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually.. for some reason each click register two click. So when I click the second one which is the nr 1 on the keyboard, it shows two ones. If i use it without a if statement it works. @BenPearlKahan

Comment: You could avoid that by listening for `keyup` instead of `keypress`, or perhaps calling `e.stop();` before the function returns. Don't forget to tick the answer if it helped!

Comment: Thanks for the reply! keyup returned 5 ones instead. Not sure how to call the stop function though.

Comment: See updated answer. I think there's something else going on in regard to the multiplication of the function...

Comment: your right - seems like its correct- Still having the problems - but your answer is correct so its something on my side.